# SVG Fill Color won't change Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, sketch-app

I have created a design in Sketch and exported it as an .svg. I then opened that .svg in Illustrator to make a few edits. I need to change the fill color of a icon that is an .svg. But I am unable too... I had the .svg red in Sketch, but when I exported the design as an .svg the icons became black.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Whatever you have selected in your screenshot (and it looks like all the icons in your layers panel) is an image trace, which you cannot change the color of (until you expand it), but if it is an SVG then there is no need to trace it, simply open it directly in Illustrator

Comment: image trace, or you placed the .svg in Ai instead of opening it.

Comment: A good place to start would be to give us the source code of the SVG, or post a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your objects have a mask applied / was traced.

What you would need to do is just click on `Expand` on the top of your screen.

It should then become *regular* vector shapes, with which the color can then easily be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expand the SVG and select it, then you will be able to change the color.

Comment: Hello Pierpaolo, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit? *How* do you expand an .svg, for example? What buttons or menu actions would that require? It's always safest to assume that the Asker is a beginner and doesn't know these things. Thanks! If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I will keep it in mind. I'm sorry if i was a bit unclear, but I am new and I had no experience on stackExchange...next time I will be more clear!